# XSD Verify Element has at least one of the attributes specified

Tags: validation, xsd, xsd-validation

Using XSD schema validation 1.0 I want to verify an element has at least one attribute specified.

For example, a simple element like this:

```
<foo a="1" b="2" c="3" />
```

I want to verify that at least attribute `b` or `c` is specified.  But note that both can also be specified--they're not mutually exclusive.

I tried using a key along the lines of:

```
    <xs:key name="AttributeSpecified">
        <xs:selector xpath="." />
        <xs:field xpath="@b|@c" />
    </xs:key>
```

but it fails when both attributes are specified (because multiple results are returned).

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in XSD 1.0. It *might* be possible in XSD 1.1.

I am a fan of XML Schema, but I would not choose it for this type of validation. You might be able to make it work using XSD1.1 but if your requirements became just a *little* more complex you could end up with some horrible-looking constraints. 
On the other hand, an XPath expression can elegantly express any constraint you can think of, and you would not need to bend the language to make it work.